# Why NFS 2 does not run on my PC?

Tags: technical-issues, need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2

My PC can run NFS MW and NFS HP2. But to my surprise it could not run NFS 2. When i open the game it appears only in the process but does not even get executed. Why is this? My OS is Windows XP.

Comment: We're going to need a lot more info than this.  What are your specs?  Do you get any errors at all?  Can you check the Event Viewer for some more info, see if there's anything in there?

Answer (score 2):

believe it or not a lot of older games have trouble playing on newer machines.  You can try running in compatibility mode by right clicking the executable->properties->compatibility/advanced and mess with some of the options there. Another trick is to only play in windowed mode. If that isnt the default you can make it so (on some games) by going into properties again, and adding "-w" to the path of the game.

heres a link to a forum post I found that also has your issue, try some of these solutions
[link here](http://www.compatdb.org/forums/topic/33329-need-for-speed-ii-se-problem-with-windows-xp/)

Comment: Usually compatibility mode with windows 98 works like a charm!